# Why does Jenkins skip the Create First Admin User wizard

Tags: jenkins

I'm working on a docker configuration that creates a Jenkins image which bootstraps it with some default jobs, some ssh keys, and a new view with plugins pre-loaded, etc.

Everything goes well, but when I run it the first time it no longer asks for the initial admin user setup in the wizard.  It does run the plugins installation step and other parts of the wizard, but not the 'create first user' page.

Does anyone know what triggers Jenkins to skip that?

As far as I know, it lets me just log in anonymously and run my jobs.
It's not necessarily a bad thing that I can do this this way, but I'd like to know what might be triggering Jenkins to skip that configuration step.

Unfortunately, I can't easily post my configuration due to work restrictions, etc. so any advice on what to look for would be greatly helpful...

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know These line in the dockerfile is triggering Jenkins to skip the First Admin User wizard:

`ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false`

That, and other [system properties are defined here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties).